# Should Tensorflow model and Tensorflow lite model output the same result?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I have a trained Tensorflow model and a Tensorflow Lite model converted from it. If I provide them with the same input, should they give me the exact same output?

Comment: No, lite model should be less accurate as it is quantized.

Comment: If I did not apply post training quantization, would they produce the same output?

Comment: Sure. If no quantization is applied, the ouputs should be the same. If not, it is a bug.